# Send an email with signature in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to send an email in VBA from Excel using Outlook signature but I get a 62 error.

This code works in another Excel worksheet.

```vb
Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim TextStream As Scripting.TextStream
Dim file_name As String
dim signature_name as string        
dim signature as string

signature_name = Sheets("Parameter").Range("A2").Value
                        
signature = ""

Set FSO = Nothing
Set TextStream = Nothing
Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
file_name = Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\" & signature_name & ".htm"
Set TextStream = FSO.OpenTextFile(file_name, ForReading, False, TristateMixed)
                        
If Err.Num = 0 Then
    signature = TextStream.ReadAll
    signature = Replace(signature, signature_name & "_files/", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\" & signature_name & "_files/")
End if
```

I checked with checkpoint that `file_name` contained the right path to the signature files.

When I try to OpenTextFile, I get an atEndOfLine = true and atEndOfStream = true.

I try checkpoint, debugging, different signature, copy/paste several codes.

When I check the err.num value, it returns 438.

Comment: Put `MsgBox filelen(file_name)` before the `Set TextStream =`.

Comment: The filename = "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\RDG-SDETI.htm". I checked, the path is right. 
By the way, this code works fine in another worksheets. I checked the reference in macro, the same library are checked

Comment: This is not what I asked.

Comment: Sorry, I red too fast :).
filelen(file_name) = 49940 oO'

Comment: Where have you assigned `signature_name`? [mcve]

Comment: I forgot to write the following line in my first message : 

signature_name = Sheets("Parameter").Range("A2").Value

but I have it in my code

Comment: Hello, I try to find which error occurs and it seems to be the 438 when I lookup for Err.num... but I still don't know why it occurs in this excel whereas in another one, with the same source code, it works fine... -_-'

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble getting my signature from `"\Microsoft\Signatures\"` or whatever address I was using. Something to do with the server I was on.

Anyway, I found this solution and it's been working for me consistently (as long as it's only your "default" signature you want:

```
Sub Build_And_Send_Email()

    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objEmail As Object
    Dim objAttachment As Object

    `...

        'Setup Email
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        'when displayed with no content, it inputs default signature
    objEmail.Display

    Set objAttachment = objEmail.Attachments
    objAttachment.Add "S:\Attachment Directory.pdf"
    eSubject = " My Subject "
    eBody = " Some text using html control for stuff like <br> line breaks "
    
        'Build Email
    With objEmail
        .To = eRecipient
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = eSubject
            ' > Signature already included in .HTMLBody
        .HTMLBody = eBody & .HTMLBody
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML ' send plain text message
        '.Display
        '.Send
    End With
    
End Sub
```

I use this everyday for multiple reports. Seems to work on multiple computers. I hope it works for you.